# Python Selenium Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to extract the date information from this web page.  I have tried every method that I would expect to work.  It seems that I am unable to extract any of the elements after many varied attempts using different driver methods. Additionally I attempted to use driver.page_source for the entire html for processing with Beautiful soup.  I was unable to find the date information in the source results captured.  I believe I must be missing something about the website.  It is a java script website.

code attempts:

```py
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("content")

elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name("GL-TVABCPFC")
```

and many others...

Source Inspection here:
[Source Inspection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pKLz.png)

Comment: driver.find_element_by_class_name("GL-TVABCPFC") - [selenium documentation for python](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)

Comment: this was my solution...I mistyped in my question.  It does not work in this case.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: If you want get text content do: ```driver.find_element_by_class_name("example").getAttribute("textContent")```

Comment: if the content is dynamically generated by JavaScript have a look at the XHR requests the website is making and then you won't have to use selenium at all .

Comment: if you want to use selenium please provide the source code

Answer (score 0):

Check whether date information is inside any iframe or not. if it is in iframe then you have to switch to that iframe then you need to call element by id or class methods.